# Wrapping a displaymath equation in surrounding text

Tags: math-mode, paragraphs, displaystyle

I don't really understand the behaviour of the indentation/paragraph building/whatever is going on (my understanding is limited...) with displaymath equations in paragraphs.
When placing an equation without any empty lines in an paragraph, I don't get any indentation after the equation, but the line is also not filled before the equation, so this is no "real" paragraph. I would like to get a behaviour like in-paragraphs floats ([h] specifier).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \parfillskip=0pt
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit 
    \begin{gather*}
        x = x - 1
    \end{gather*}
    anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

With some fine-tuning of the text (I pushed "anim id est laborum." after the equation, I can almost fill the line before the equation, with `\parfillskip=0pt` I get rid of the small space.
[image: example1]
This however also ruins the last line, obviously. I could set `\parfillskip` back to it's original value after the equation, but what it the best approach here. And what is the reasoning behind this behaviour? Why do we get these "half" paragraphs? Note that in my real-life example I'm using labels for the equations, so they don't have to absolutely be where they where mentioned in the source.

Comment: why do you want to fill the last line before the equation? for short paragraphs that isn't normally possible without massively over-stretching the white space.

Comment: equations are not floats, tex never moves them and they will always appear exactly where you place them in the source.

Comment: unrelated, but you should not use `gather` for single line equations.

Comment: @David Carlisle of course. And thank you for your detailed answer

Comment: For TeX, LaTeX, and friends, the word "paragraph" has a very specific meaning, and this meaning need not coincide with its meaning in ordinary speech. The body of your test document, starting with the first "Lorem ipsum" and ending with the final "est laborum", forms a *single* paragraph as far as TeX is concerned. The fact that this paragraph comprises a displayed, numbered equation does *not* make it two-paragraph-plus-one-displayed-equation object. (If it did, the first line after the displayed equation would exhibit a paragraph indent...)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why wouldn't I want to fill the line? Of course for short paragraphs this doesn't make sense, but I find this related to the placement of float in paragraphs (see for example my question about this for floats: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533219/specifying-number-of-lines-before-after-float-in-paragraphs).

Comment: You could use \linebreak before the equation, but gather* would probably think it was between paragraphs ind increase the vertical space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equations are not floats, they always appear at the point they are entered in the text. The text above is set as a "partial paragraph" with a forced linebreak and `\parfillskip`
the following text is set as a continuation (so no paragraph indent) unless preceded by a blank line to start a new paragraph.

For equations this is built in to the tex program, but LaTeX emulates the same behaviour with all its display constructs such as an `enumerate` list which will be set in-paragraph with no following paragraph indentation.

---

It's a rather unusual setting but if you absolutely want the equation not to disturb the line breaking you could use `\vadjust` but then you would probably need to adjust the vertical spacing slightly as you would lose the normal vertical math spacing adjustments.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit 
    \begin{gather*}
        x = x - 1
    \end{gather*}
    anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\bigskip


    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit%
    \vadjust{\begin{gather*}
        x = x - 1
    \end{gather*}}
    anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively if you want to really consider all display math constructs as floats then you can declare a new float type (which is a few low level commands or as here a single declaration using the `float` package. This declares a new `eqn` counter that isn't really used (but could be used with `\caption` as I'm assuming here that you would use this with numbered equations (so I used `gather` not `gather*`) I declared the default placement to be `[htbp]` so in particular it included `h` unlike the defaults for `figure` and `table`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What bugs me is why is this unusual? We have labels for equations to refer to them, similar as floats that appear in a paragraph (h, not p, t or b). Why would I want to have a partial paragraph and why is that the default? As always, typography is a matter of taste, but the second example looks better to me, at least.

Comment: @pschulz I mean it's unusual as Ive never seen equations set that way in maths journals. What you prefer is of course a matter of choice, but what has historically been the norm is a matter of record.

Comment: @pschulz the second example looks better but it is nonsense text. The norm for mathematicians writing is that the mathematics is part of the narrative text and can not be re-ordered to make things fit any more than words can be re-ordered. Floating images may be referred to indirectly  so their positions may be changed, but mathematics is part of the sentence structure and moving it is like moving words, it is possible (and you can get better line breaks if you do) but it requires knowledge of the subject matter.

Comment: Hm, I agree that in most cases equations are used as part of the narrative text. I must say that I often find this creates weird-sounding sentences. With referring to equations by labels one can avoid this, hence my request.

Comment: @pschulz the alternative is to define a new float type like figure and then wrap every display math in `\begin{eqn}[htp]`  just as you wrap `tabular` in `table` and `\includegraphics` in `figure` Perhaps that is the answer you are looking for? I could add a version that does that.

Comment: that sounds good, and I have no idea how that is done. I would be happy to see this solution, thank you very much!

Comment: @pschulz I was out on my once a day escape from lockdown. just got back and added the float version.